# why left position does not work in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var fn_paragraph_diaporama_controls = function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 991) {
        if ($('.o-paragraph-diaporama').length > 0) {
            $('.o-paragraph-diaporama').each(function () {
                $(this).find('.tns-controls').css("left", $(this).find('.o-paragraph-diaporama__item').width() - $(this).find('.tns-controls').width());
            });
        }

        if ($('.o-paragraph-temoignage').length > 0) {
            $('.o-paragraph-temoignage').each(function () {
                $(this).find('.tns-controls').css("left", $(this).find('.o-paragraph-temoignage__item').width() - $(this).find('.tns-controls').width());
            });
        }

        if ($('.o-paragraph-partenaires').length > 0) {
            $('.o-paragraph-partenaires').each(function () {
                $(this).find('.tns-controls').css("left", $(this).find('.o-paragraph-partenaires__item').width() - $(this).find('.tns-controls').width());
            });
        }
    }
};
```

```css
.o-paragraph-diaporama {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     margin-top: 5rem;
     margin-bottom: 5rem;
     background-color: teal;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama .tns-controls {
     display: inline-flex;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 5rem;
     right: 0;
     width: 10rem;
     z-index: 1039;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama .btn-controls {
     font-size: 1.6rem;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama .btn-controls[disabled] {
     opacity: 0.4;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__item {
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 5rem;
     height: 41.3rem;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__img {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     z-index: -1;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__img img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     object-fit: cover;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__img figure {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__img figcaption {
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     right: 0;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__text {
     display: flex;
     align-items: flex-end;
     padding: 2rem 2rem 7rem 2rem;
     height: 100%;
     line-height: 2;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__text::after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 100%);
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__title {
     margin-bottom: 0;
     line-height: 1.5;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__lead {
     margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__text-inner {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 2;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper:not(.tns-slide-active) {
     opacity: 0.7;
}
 .o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper:not(.tns-slide-active) .o-paragraph-diaporama__text, .o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper:not(.tns-slide-active) .o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen {
     visibility: hidden;
}

.tns-outer{padding:0 !important}.tns-outer [hidden]{display:none !important}.tns-outer [aria-controls],.tns-outer [data-action]{cursor:pointer}.tns-slider{-webkit-transition:all 0s;-moz-transition:all 0s;transition:all 0s}.tns-slider>.tns-item{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.tns-horizontal.tns-subpixel{white-space:nowrap}.tns-horizontal.tns-subpixel>.tns-item{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;white-space:normal}.tns-horizontal.tns-no-subpixel:after{content:'';display:table;clear:both}.tns-horizontal.tns-no-subpixel>.tns-item{float:left}.tns-horizontal.tns-carousel.tns-no-subpixel>.tns-item{margin-right:-100%}.tns-no-calc{position:relative;left:0}.tns-gallery{position:relative;left:0;min-height:1px}.tns-gallery>.tns-item{position:absolute;left:-100%;-webkit-transition:transform 0s, opacity 0s;-moz-transition:transform 0s, opacity 0s;transition:transform 0s, opacity 0s}.tns-gallery>.tns-slide-active{position:relative;left:auto !important}.tns-gallery>.tns-moving{-webkit-transition:all 0.25s;-moz-transition:all 0.25s;transition:all 0.25s}.tns-autowidth{display:inline-block}.tns-lazy-img{-webkit-transition:opacity 0.6s;-moz-transition:opacity 0.6s;transition:opacity 0.6s;opacity:0.6}.tns-lazy-img.tns-complete{opacity:1}.tns-ah{-webkit-transition:height 0s;-moz-transition:height 0s;transition:height 0s}.tns-ovh{overflow:hidden}.tns-visually-hidden{position:absolute;left:-10000em}.tns-transparent{opacity:0;visibility:hidden}.tns-fadeIn{opacity:1;filter:alpha(opacity=100);z-index:0}.tns-normal,.tns-fadeOut{opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity=0);z-index:-1}.tns-vpfix{white-space:nowrap}.tns-vpfix>div,.tns-vpfix>li{display:inline-block}.tns-t-subp2{margin:0 auto;width:310px;position:relative;height:10px;overflow:hidden}.tns-t-ct{width:2333.3333333%;width:-webkit-calc(100% * 70 / 3);width:-moz-calc(100% * 70 / 3);width:calc(100% * 70 / 3);position:absolute;right:0}.tns-t-ct:after{content:'';display:table;clear:both}.tns-t-ct>div{width:1.4285714%;width:-webkit-calc(100% / 70);width:-moz-calc(100% / 70);width:calc(100% / 70);height:10px;float:left}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.3/tiny-slider.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>

<div class="o-paragraph-diaporama">
    <div class="container-content">
        <div class="tns-outer" id="tns1-ow">
            <div class="tns-controls" aria-label="Carousel Navigation" tabindex="0" style="background: red; left: -100px;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-controls btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only" data-controls="prev" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tns1" disabled="">
                    <span class="btn-text sr-only">Slide précédente</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-controls btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only" data-controls="next" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tns1">
                    <span class="btn-text sr-only">Slide suivante</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="tns-liveregion tns-visually-hidden" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">slide
                <span class="current">1</span>
                of 4</div>
            <div id="tns1-mw" class="tns-ovh">
                <div class="tns-inner" id="tns1-iw">
                    <div class="js-paragraph-diaporama  tns-slider tns-carousel tns-subpixel tns-calc tns-horizontal" id="tns1" style="transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item tns-slide-active" id="tns1-item0">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">
                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text">
                                    <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text-inner">
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__title h3">Item 01 - Title</p>
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__lead">Item 01 - Lead</p>
                                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__btn">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-active-effect btn-width--md btn--ghost btn--white">Item 01 - Bouton
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/nature" alt="">
                                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right">Item 01 - Image caption</figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/1730/971/nature" data-modaal-desc="Item 01 - Image caption" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_1632148741508c9547288a02bf">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item" id="tns1-item1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/tech" alt="">
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/850/850/tech" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_1632148741508b3607805b0e3">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item" id="tns1-item2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">
                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text">
                                    <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text-inner">
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__title h3">Item 03 - soluta provident quibusdam nemo et in, alias nihil atque eaque velit aperiam repellat</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/arch" alt="">
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/1250/650/arch" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_163214874150860497234fa8b1">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item" id="tns1-item3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">
                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text">
                                    <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text-inner">
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__title h3">Item 04 - Title</p>
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__lead">Item 04 - soluta provident quibusdam nemo et in, alias nihil atque eaque velit aperiam soluta provident quibusdam nemo et in, alias nihil atque eaque velit aperiam</p>
                                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__btn">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-active-effect btn-width--md btn--plain btn--accent">Item 04 - Bouton
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/nature" alt="">
                                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right">Item 04 - Image caption</figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/1730/971/nature" data-modaal-desc="Item 04 - Image caption" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_1632148741508972b5688046a6">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am trying to make a position left on butons according to the item width.
when i make a `console.log` to see the left value, it appears on the browser console, but when i assign it to the left `proprety` to the buttons, it does not work.

this is my js:

```
if ($('.o-paragraph-diaporama__item').length > 0) {
    $('.o-paragraph-diaporama__item').each(function () {
        item    = $(this);
        buttons = $('.tns-controls');
        left = $(this).width() - buttons.width();
        buttons.css({
            "background": "red",
            left: left
        });
        console.log("left  ", left);
        console.log("item width ", item.width() );
    });
}
```

My HTML :

```
<div class="o-paragraph-diaporama">
    <div class="container-content">
        <div class="tns-outer" id="tns1-ow">
            <div class="tns-controls" aria-label="Carousel Navigation" tabindex="0" style="background: red; left: -100px;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-controls btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only" data-controls="prev" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tns1" disabled="">
                    <span class="btn-text sr-only">Slide précédente</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-controls btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only" data-controls="next" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tns1">
                    <span class="btn-text sr-only">Slide suivante</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="tns-liveregion tns-visually-hidden" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">slide
                <span class="current">1</span>
                of 4</div>
            <div id="tns1-mw" class="tns-ovh">
                <div class="tns-inner" id="tns1-iw">
                    <div class="js-paragraph-diaporama  tns-slider tns-carousel tns-subpixel tns-calc tns-horizontal" id="tns1" style="transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px);">
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item tns-slide-active" id="tns1-item0">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">
                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text">
                                    <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text-inner">
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__title h3">Item 01 - Title</p>
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__lead">Item 01 - Lead</p>
                                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__btn">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-active-effect btn-width--md btn--ghost btn--white">Item 01 - Bouton
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/nature" alt="">
                                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right">Item 01 - Image caption</figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/1730/971/nature" data-modaal-desc="Item 01 - Image caption" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_1632148741508c9547288a02bf">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item" id="tns1-item1" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/tech" alt="">
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/850/850/tech" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_1632148741508b3607805b0e3">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item" id="tns1-item2" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">
                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text">
                                    <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text-inner">
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__title h3">Item 03 - soluta provident quibusdam nemo et in, alias nihil atque eaque velit aperiam repellat</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/arch" alt="">
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/1250/650/arch" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_163214874150860497234fa8b1">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item-wrapper tns-item" id="tns1-item3" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
                            <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__item text-white">
                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text">
                                    <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__text-inner">
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__title h3">Item 04 - Title</p>
                                        <p class="o-paragraph-diaporama__lead">Item 04 - soluta provident quibusdam nemo et in, alias nihil atque eaque velit aperiam soluta provident quibusdam nemo et in, alias nihil atque eaque velit aperiam</p>
                                        <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__btn">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-active-effect btn-width--md btn--plain btn--accent">Item 04 - Bouton
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="o-paragraph-diaporama__img">
                                    <figure class="figure">
                                        <img src="http://placeimg.com/730/410/nature" alt="">
                                        <figcaption class="figure-caption text-right">Item 04 - Image caption</figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn--plain btn--primary btn-icon-only o-paragraph-diaporama__fullscreen" data-group="group-diaporama-01" data-modaal-content-source="http://placeimg.com/1730/971/nature" data-modaal-desc="Item 04 - Image caption" title="Afficher en plein écran" data-modaal-scope="modaal_1632148741508972b5688046a6">
                                    <span class="icon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    <span class="sr-only">Afficher en plein écran</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i have :
[image]

What i should have :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[The `left` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left#description):

- Only applies to elements which are *positioned* (i.e. have a `position` property that is not `static` (the default).
- Takes a length and not a number (i.e.  you need to include units such as `px` in the value)

Comment: hey, for your 1st point, why it is working with     `left =  buttons.width();` and for your second point, if i assign 500 to the proprety, the browser add automaticaly 'px'

Comment: @meryemmereyemm — Only if you are in [Quirks mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode) which is a nightmare of browser inconsistencies that you should avoid. Not requiring units was a bug in ancient browsers that is emulated for backwards compatibility with sites that were written for those browsers. It isn't good practice to write new code against those bugs.

Comment: what about the position that you mentioned it ? You said that left prop is only applied to the element whith position 'statis' for example, but why it's working with `left =  buttons.width();`  ?